# SQL join results in columns

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, join

I have a table of **Wearers** and a table of **SKUs**. A Wearer can have multiple SKUs, and when they match, I want to see that result. Traditionally, I would show the results like this:

```
WEARER      SKU
------------------
Wearer 1    SKU 38    
Wearer 2    SKU 47
Wearer 2    SKU 75
Wearer 3    SKU 38
Wearer 7    SKU 47
Wearer 7    SKU 99
```

However, the person requesting this query wants to see it like this:

```
WEARER      SKU 1     SKU 2    SKU 3    ...
-------------------------------------------
Wearer 1    SKU 38
Wearer 2    SKU 47    SKU 75
Wearer 3    SKU 38
Wearer 7    SKU 47    SKU 99
```

So, for every matching SKU to a Wearer, create a column for that SKU. What would be the proper method of going about this style of join in T-SQL (SQL Server)?

Some information:

- A Wearer would not have more than 10 SKUs assigned to them.

Comment: Do you know the maximum number of SKUs?  A SQL query has a fixed number of columns, so if you don't know, then you need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: I've never seen more than 10. I'll add this to my question.

Comment: Have you looked at using a pivot having done your join? Could you show the script you have for the join.

Comment: You might not need this now but I would definitely recommend checking this out - https://www.sqlrelease.com/dynamic-pivot-query-in-sql-server

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure it is not going to go more than 10, then you can use conditional aggregation here:

```
;with tableA as
(select 'Wearer 1' as Wearer,'SKU 38' as SKU union
select 'Wearer 2','SKU 47' union
select 'Wearer 2','SKU 75' union
select 'Wearer 3','SKU 38' union
select 'Wearer 7','SKU 47' union
select 'Wearer 7','SKU 99')

select x.Wearer,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rownum1=1 then SKU end) as SKU_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rownum1=2 then SKU end) as SKU_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rownum1=3 then SKU end) as SKU_3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rownum1=4 then SKU end) as SKU_4,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rownum1=5 then SKU end) as SKU_5,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rownum1=6 then SKU end) as SKU_6,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rownum1=7 then SKU end) as SKU_7,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rownum1=8 then SKU end) as SKU_8,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rownum1=9 then SKU end) as SKU_9,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rownum1=10 then SKU end) as SKU_10
from
(select a.*,
       row_number() over (partition by Wearer order by SKU) as rownum1
from tableA a) x
Group by x.Wearer
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you wanted to try the `PIVOT` approach.

**Example**

```
Select *
 From (
        Select WEARER
              ,SKU
              ,Col = concat('SKU ',row_number() over (partition by wearer order by SKU) )
         from YourTable
      ) src
 Pivot (max(SKU) for Col in ([SKU 1],[SKU 2],[SKU 3],[SKU 4],[SKU 5] ) ) pvt
```

**Returns**

```
WEARER      SKU 1   SKU 2   SKU 3   SKU 4   SKU 5
Wearer 1    SKU 38  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Wearer 2    SKU 47  SKU 75  NULL    NULL    NULL
Wearer 3    SKU 38  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Wearer 7    SKU 47  SKU 99  NULL    NULL    NULL
```

**EDIT - If you Don't want NULL values**

```
Select WEARER
      ,[SKU 1] = concat('',[1])
      ,[SKU 2] = concat('',[2])
      ,[SKU 3] = concat('',[3])
      ,[SKU 4] = concat('',[4])
      ,[SKU 5] = concat('',[5])
 From (
        Select WEARER
              ,SKU
              ,Col = row_number() over (partition by wearer order by SKU) 
         from YourTable
      ) src
 Pivot (max(SKU) for Col in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5] ) ) pvt
```